# How to find percentage of "empty" values columnwise

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote this snippet to find out what is the percentage of each column, that contains `empty` values.

When I do it for one column **it works** like this, where `DESCRIPTION` is the column in action.

```
for ind, column in enumerate(df.columns[0:]):
    tmp = df.columns[ind]
    print(ind, df.columns[ind], ((df[df['DESCRIPTION'] == 'empty'].shape[0])/(df.shape[0]))*100)
```

while when I try to enumerate same thing for all columns, it doesn't work. I have declared @tmp as the variable to be used for column names.

```
for ind, column in enumerate(df.columns[0:]):
    tmp = df.columns[ind]
    print(ind, df.columns[ind], ((df[df[@tmp] == 'empty'].shape[0])/(df.shape[0]))*100)
```

Please help !!

Comment: What is your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for col in df.columns.tolist():
    print(col, df[col], df[col][df[col] == 'empty'].shape[0] / df[col].shape[0]*100)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, throws an error saying `TypeError: invalid type comparison
`

Comment: Can you check once ?

Comment: Maybe you have some numerical columns, does this work like this (with .astype(str) : print(col, df[col], df[col][df[col].astype(str) == 'empty'].shape[0] / df[col].shape[0]*100) ?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,'empty'],'b':['empty','empty',3]})
print(('%d'%(([x for i in df.values.tolist() for x in i].count('empty')/len([x for i in df.values.tolist() for x in i]))*100))+'%')
```

Output:

```
50%
```